# Recursive search on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written an excel VBA code for user to input an id and the corresponding data from the data sheet of excel will get displayed as the output

```
Sub finddata()
    Dim North As Long
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Sheets("ML").Range("K5:P200").ClearContents
    North = Sheets("ML").Range("K2").Value
    finalrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Columns(1))
    For i = 2 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 4) = North Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
            Range("K100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Now I need to modify the code to search the result recursively. For e.g - the output cell ids from the above search are also present in Parent Cell id field with different Con Number. We need to enlist those also. This loop should go on until the complete set is displayed. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: you could do all this work with formulas and/or [Contextures.com: advanced filter](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html) and [Contextures.com: Advanced Filter Programming](http://www.contextures.com/exceladvancedfiltervba.html) ...

Comment: please clarify what you want - ideally with some sample data showing how the second part is supposed to work...

Comment: Seems like you should look into .findnext. Also, this way you won't have to go through ALL rows, which slows things down.

Comment: @newuser1: why have you edited to remove the image showing what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in one comment you should go with .findnext; with that said, I'll try this:

```
Sub finddata()

Dim North As Long
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim count As Long

Sheets("ML").Range("K5:P200").ClearContents
North = Sheets("ML").Range("K2").Value
finalrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Columns(1))

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F" & finalrow)

    Set cellid = .Cells.Find(What:=North)

    If Not cellid Is Nothing Then

        Do Until cellid Is Nothing

            Range(Cells(cellid.Row, 1), Cells(cellid.Row, 6)).Copy
            Range("K100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

            Set cellid = .FindNext(cellid)
        Loop

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you can it without a loop using Advanced Filter - see my answer

Comment: @IRENE G, thanks for your answer. I have tried the above.Unfortunately its not giving the desired result. From the Parent Cell ID lets say "96280" we are getting Cell Ids "11011", ''11012". But this Cell Id "11011" can be present in the ParentCELLID column too. So we need to get the results of the child for this. And also "96280" can be child of other parents. In this way we need to form the tree

Answer (score 0):

or maybe just use Advanced Filter:

```
sub findRecords()

    Range("K3:P200").ClearContents

    Range("A1:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "K1:K2"), CopyToRange:=Range("K5"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

you could even put this in the Worksheet code module in the `onChange` event, and have it run automatically every time the criteria is set in cell **K2** like this:

1. Right-click the sheet tab, and click `View Code`
2. Paste in the below code:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Len(Target) >= 5 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
   Else
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Range("K3:P200").ClearContents

   Range("A1:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
           "K1:K2"), CopyToRange:=Range("K5"), Unique:=False

   Application.EnableEvents = True

   End Sub
   ```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Our Man in Bananas, thanks for your comments. From the Parent Cell ID  lets say "96280" we are getting Cell Ids "11011", ''11012". But this Cell Id "11011" can be present in the ParentCELLID column too. So we need to get the results of the child for this. And also "96280" can be child of other parents. In this way we need to form the tree

Comment: @newuser1: for that, you could add further `Advanced Filter` calls using the results in K5-P5 ... so you filter the results *unique records only* to another location, and for each result, call the Adv Filter operation...